# Identify template for lecture notes

Tags: templates

Very simple, but does anyone know which LaTeX template these [lecture notes](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~ionides/620/notes/markov_chains.pdf) are done in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an easy template to copy, you can start with something like this, and further tune things as you want:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\section{Markov Chains}

\begin{itemize}
\item The Markov property is common in probability
models because, by assumption, one supposes
that the important variables for the system being
modeled are all included in the state space.
\item The Markov property is common in probability
models because, by assumption, one supposes
that the important variables for the system being
modeled are all included in the state space.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Save this code as satz.sty and import into an amsart class. Code inspired and borrowed from [Some Fundamental Theorems in Mathematics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.08416), which by the way is an excellent read.

```
%% inpired and code borrowed from
%% https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.08416 by Oliver Knill
%% E-mail: yannislaz@gmail.com
%% Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
%% See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Use with amsart class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2017/04/15]%
\ProvidesPackage{satz}[2019/2/13 v1.0 Math lecture notes (YL)]%
%%
%% Geometry
\setlength{\parindent}{1em} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.0cm} \setlength{\headheight}{0.5cm} \setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{17.0cm}
%% Packages
\RequirePackage{latexsym}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{comment}
\RequirePackage[section]{placeins}
%% theorems
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} \newtheorem{propo}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{satz}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
%% colors
\definecolor{red1}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.9} \definecolor{blue1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1} \definecolor{green1}{rgb}{0.9,1,0.9}
\definecolor{yellow1}{rgb}{1,1,0.8} \definecolor{yellow2}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{color11}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.6}
%% sectioning
\def\chapter#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{green1}{green1}{ \parbox{16.2cm}{{\Large {\bf #1}}}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
%% miscellaneous
\def\idea#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{yellow2}{yellow2}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Idea:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\question#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{blue1}{blue1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Question:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\conjecture#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{green1}{green1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Conjecture:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\remark#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{yellow1}{yellow1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Remark:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\satz#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{yellow1}{yellow1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Theorem:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\coro#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{yellow1}{yellow1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Corollary:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\def\definition#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{red1}{red1}{ \parbox{14.0cm}{{\bf Definition:} #1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
%% shorthand math commands
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}} \newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\mathbb{H}} \newcommand{\OO}{\mathbb{O}} \newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}} \newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}} \newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\Sphere}{\mathcal{S}}
\def\osquare{\mbox{\ooalign{$\times$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}} }
\def\Bin#1#2{{#1\choose #2}}
\def\h#1{\fcolorbox{blue1}{blue1}{\begin{large}#1\end{large}}}
\newcounter{example}
\def\example#1{ \item \fontsize{12}{15} \selectfont #1 \fontsize{12}{15} \selectfont }
\definecolor{yellow2}{rgb}{1,1,0.9}
\def\tweet#1{ \vspace{2mm} \begin{center} \fcolorbox{yellow2}{yellow2}{ \parbox{11.2cm}{#1}} \vspace{2mm} \end{center} }
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{9}{9} \selectfont OLIVER KNILL}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{9}{9} \selectfont FUNDAMENTAL THEOREMS}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\endinput
%% end add anythigng more you need
```

At the arxiv.org link shown, you can also download the paper as .tex and see how it was used.